# How to automatically enable autostart my apps in Xiaomi Mi4i security menu?

Tags: android, service, autostart

My apps if already install, can't start service. If running service must setup in Security Menu and then allow this apps with manual setting. And i want for setup not manual setup but with programmatically in my code service.

My Code,

- Service

  public class MyService extends Service {

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
  }
  ```

  }
- Android Manifest

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <service
          android:name=".MyService"
          android:exported="false"
          android:enabled="true">
      </service>
  </application>
  ```

Please Help me anyone.. :'(

Comment: Any solutions you received yet?

Comment: no solutions. maybe anyone got any solution?

Comment: I wonder how WhatsApp and some other apps auto-start permission is granted by default.